# xpath select by attribute when attribute not present

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Short question:
I would like to select all nodes that do not match an attribute (@type !='x') but also attribute doesn't exist (??).
Currently, I'm getting nothing back, because the other nodes have no attribute at all.

Background:
I have some XML. Note that one has type="feature" but all others have no 'type' attr.

```
<image type="feature"><description>X</description><url>media/designer_glass_tile_04.jpg</url><height></height><width/></image>
<image><description>Designer Glass 05</description><url>media/designer_glass_tile_05.jpg</url><height></height><width/></image>
<image><description>Designer Glass 06</description><url>media/designer_glass_tile_06.jpg</url><height></height><width/></image>
<image><description>Designer Glass 07</description><url>media/designer_glass_tile_07.jpg</url><height></height><width/></image>
<image><description>Designer Glass 08</description><url>media/designer_glass_tile_08.jpg</url><height></height><width/></image>
```

And a XSL style:

```
        <div id="gallery">
            <div id="feature" >
                <xsl:apply-templates select="image[@type='feature']"/>
            </div>
            <div id="thumbs">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="image[@type!='feature']"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The following code will select all nodes where type attribute doesn't exist:

```
select="image[not(@type)]"
```

Add this logic in your code.

Answer (score 14):

Try using `not()` instead of `!=` in the predicate...

```
   <div id="gallery">
        <div id="feature" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="image[@type='feature']"/>
        </div>
        <div id="thumbs">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="image[not(@type='feature')]"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```