# Extract and sanatize XML data with XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to extract all attributes names, IDs, and values, because the data needs to be imported into another system.

```
   <ATTRIBUTES>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME="TOLERANCE" ID="AT000"></ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME="CHANGED_AT">
            <VALUE>2019-01-31</VALUE>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME="CHANGED_BY" ID="AT002"></ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME="WEIGHT_UNIT" ID="AT003">
            <VALUE>kg</VALUE>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
    </ATTRIBUTES>
```

The problem is `ATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE/@ID` and `ATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE/#VALUE` only return existing data and do not indicate nodes that don't have an `ID` or an `value` element.

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807499/xpath-select-by-attribute-when-attribute-not-present), where someone searched for attributes that didn't match or didn't exist, but I can't translate the code to fit my needs.

How can I can extract sane data with XPath that keeps the data integritiy intact?

Comment: Don't use XPath, or use it only to get the list of `<ATTRIBUTE>` elements. Then handle this list with something else than XPath.

Comment: Xpath 1.0 returns node-sets (unordered, deduplicated list of nodes). You cannot select a node that doesn't exist. You should use the hosting language to further process like emiting some default information when an XPath expression returns an empty node-set ("not found").

Comment: I use two XPath expressions now. The first to extract all attribute nodes and a second expression which relative to a single attribute node.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you parse the xml using Jsoup-library. It's aimed at reading xml in an html-context. It has several methods to find elements by Css-selector, id, or matching a value on an attribute or inverse-matching a value on an attribute, to find attribute values directly, etc.

Just use the Jsoup.connect method to connect to a url. That will return a Document (J-soup node specialization). From that point on you have a wide range of methods available to extract data from the Document.

https://jsoup.org/

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3